# Why does the profiler show large numbers of char[] instances when I am not creating any?

Tags: java, profiling

I am running a NetBeans profile of a recursive operation that includes creating a class with a `java.lang.String` field. In the classes list, in the profile heap dump, the number of String fields corresponds to the number of classes created as expected, however there are also a similar number of `char[]` instances. The char arrays account for nearly 70% of the memory usage(!) whilst the String field accounts for about 7%.

What is going on here? And how can I reduce the number of `char[]` instances?

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Take a look at the [String source code](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/lang/String.java.html). The String object itself contains a cached hash code, a count of the number of characters (again, for optimisation purposes), an offset (since a `String.substr()` points to the original string data) *and* the character array, which contains the actual string data. Hence your metrics showing that String consumes relatively little, but the majority of memory is taken by the underlying character arrays.

Answer (score 4):

> The char arrays account for nearly 70%
>   of the memory usage(!) whilst the
>   String field accounts for about 7%

This is subtlety of memory profiling known as "retained size" and "shallow size":

- *Shallow size* refers to how much memory is taken up by an object, not including any child objects it contains. Basically, this means primitive fields.
- *Retained size* is the shallow size plus the size of the other objects referred to by the object, but *only* those other objects which are referred to only by this object (tricky to explain, simple concept).

String is the perfect example. It contains a handful of primitive fields, plus the `char[]`. The `char[]` accounts for the vast majority of the memory usage. The shallow size of String is very small, but it's retained size is much larger, since that includes the `char[]`.

The NetBeans profiler is probably giving you the shallow size, which isn't a very useful figure, but is easy to calculate. The retained size would incorporate the `char[]` memory usage into the `String` memory usage, but calculating the retained size is computationally expensive, and so profilers won't work that out until explicitly asked to.

Comment: I think you mean char[], not byte[]

Comment: @PeterLawrey oh the irony. Nowadays, since Java 9, `byte[]` would be indeed the correct type (but that would also change the initial question)…

Answer (score 2):

The `String` class in the Sun's Java implementation uses a `char[]` to store the character data.

I believe this can be verified without looking at the source code by using a debugger to look at the contents of a `String`, or by using reflection to look at the internals of the `String` object.

Therefore, it would be difficult to reduce the number of `char[]` which are being created, unless the number of `String` instances which are being created were reduced.

Answer (score 1):

Strings are backed by char arrays, so I don't think you can reduce the number of char[] instances without reducing your Strings.

Have you tried removing some Strings to see if the char[]s go down as well?